# How can I execute tests in a crate that gets developed for a "non default target", like UEFI?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm developing an application for the `x86_64-unknown-uefi` target with Rust/Cargo 1.55-nightly. My `.cargo/config.toml` looks like this:

```
[unstable]
build-std = [
    "alloc",
    "compiler_builtins",
    "core",
]

build-std-features = ["compiler-builtins-mem"]

[build]
target = "x86_64-unknown-uefi"
```

My minimal code example looks like this:

```rust
#![no_std]
#![no_main]
// allow inline assembly
#![feature(asm)]
// compile target with efi abi calling convention
#![feature(abi_efiapi)]

#[macro_use]
extern crate alloc;


use uefi::prelude::*;

#[entry]
fn efi_main(_image_handler: uefi::Handle, system_table: SystemTable<Boot>) -> Status {
    loop {}
    Status::SUCCESS
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use crate::config::BootModule;

    #[test]
    fn test_hello() {
        assert!(true)
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `test`
  --> src/main.rs:40:5
   |
39 |       #[test]
   |       ------- in this procedural macro expansion
40 | /     fn test_hello() {
41 | |         assert!(true)
42 | |     }
   | |_____^ can't find crate
```

How can I execute tests in a crate that gets developed for a "non default target", like UEFI?

I tried several things, like

```
[unstable]
build-std = [
    "alloc",
    "compiler_builtins",
    "core",
    + "test",
]
```

With this change the compiler tells me to `add #![feature(restricted_std)]`. I did so, but nothing changes (and the same message repeats).

What is going on here and how can I execute tests?

Comment: Quoting from https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/cargo/reference/unstable.html#build-std: *"Using -Z build-std will implicitly compile the stable crates core, std, alloc, and proc_macro. If you're using cargo test it will also compile the test crate. If you're working with an environment which does not support some of these crates, then you can pass an argument to -Zbuild-std as well:"* so this *should* work. Do you use `cargo test` or what do you execute to run your test?

Comment: `cargo test`, yes. With `$ cargo test -Zbuild-std` I get the same error as shown at the bottom of my question; I should add `#![feature(restricted_std)]` which doesn't has any effect in the end..

Comment: Then I would say it's a bug in the current implementation of `build-std` and you should file a bug at the github repository. Will you do that, or should I open a ticket?

Comment: I can do it. Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/rust-lang/wg-cargo-std-aware/issues/69 
this seems to be related to your issue, but make sure that you file one for your specific case, e.g. executing tests :)

Comment: Bug report: https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/9710